# Runtime question - loading and bliting images

Tags: python, pygame

I cant blit images in normal speed if the images in array.
#brife review
In my code i defined 10 images as a variable(x1-x10)
those 100 images relevant for specific class (object.draw_function()), and will be bliting in main loop according specific condtions.
in the object.draw_function() all the images are saved in lst "images_lst" = [img1,img2,img3,,,,img10]
and bliting from that array according rulles.

i noticed that if the len of the array is higher then 4,5 , the loop FPS is slower. and i dont understand why ? the loading images is outside the loop.

Code example:

```
#loading images
img1 = pygame.image.load(r'images\game_background1\img1.jpg')
img2 = pygame.image.load(r'images\game_background1\img2.jpg')
img3 = pygame.image.load(r'images\game_background1\img3.jpg')
'
'
'
img10= pygame.image.load(r'images\game_background1\img10.png')

#define font and space size
space_width,space_height = pysical_tm_img.get_width(),pysical_tm_img.get_height() 
font0_0 = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_fonts()[0],12)
font0_02 = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_fonts()[0],17)    

# define class
class EXAMPLE():
    def __init__(self,x,y,text,power,energy,range):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,100,10)
        self.text = text
        self.power = power
        self.energy = energy
        self.range = range

    def draw_func(self,surface):
                img_lst = [img1,text1,img2,text2,img3,text3......img10,text10] 
   
        for i,img in enumerate(img_lst):
            if i % 2 == 0 :
                img_rect = img.get_rect(center=(self.rect.x +20 +  (i *space_width*2),self.rect.top + space_height))
                surface.blit(img,img_rect)
            else:
                img_rect = img.get_rect(center=(self.rect.x +20 + space_width + ((i-1) *space_width*2),self.rect.top + space_height))
                surface.blit(img,img_rect)
         

#main loop
while True:
      if somthing:
          object1 = EXAMPLE(10,10,"abc",100,50,10)
          object1.draw_func(screen)
      elif somthing else:
          object3 = EXAMPLE(10,10,"abc",100,50,10)
          object3.draw_func(screen)

    
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

1. I dont understand whats wrong and why i cant append more images to my images list without reducing runtime.
2. Another question that not much relevant to this code but rellevant to runtime. if this code without the main loop is in file number 1  and in this file i import pygame and  init the font only.

```
 pygame.font.init()
```

and in file num 2 where the main loop is running i import pygame and init pygame

```
 pygame.init()
```

is it reduce my proggram runtime?

Comment: Of course, it takes more time to blit more images. If the images cannot be `blit`in 1/60 of a second  (`clock.tick (60)`) , the frame rate drops. There is nothing unusual about that.

Comment: Load the images into a list. It's a lot easier: `imglist = [pygame.image.load(r'images\game_background1\img' + str(i) + '.png') for i in range(1, 11)]`

Comment: @Rabbid76 But in other function i bliting many more images (around 40) in same loop. here just 10 , what have i did wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. Are the images larger in size?

Comment: @Rabbid76 about load images into list i agree. its easier in terms of code logic but not in terms of runtime. am i right?

Comment: the images is 20X15 pixels only

Comment: No the images are just loaded once. An extra variable for each image is awful to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the image *Surface* has the same format as the display *Surface*. Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) (or [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)) to create a *Surface* that has the same pixel format. This improves performance when the image is `blit` on  the display, because the formats are compatible and `blit` does not need to perform an implicit transformation.

e.g.:

```py
img1 = pygame.image.load(r'images\game_background1\img1.jpg').convert()
```